# An integral with residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to calculate the following integral using the residual method
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}dx\frac{n \cos(x)(-a + 2r\cos(x))\sin(n(x+t))-(a-2)\cos(n(x+t))\sin(x)}{(a-2r\cos(x))^2} $$
where $n$ is a positive integer, $a$ is a positive real and $t \in(0,2\pi]$. The integral is done on the circle of radius 1.

Calling $z=e^{ix}$ I tried to calculate the pole contained in the circle $|z|=1$ and use the method of residuals. The poles are identified by the condition
$$ (a-r(z^{-1}+z) )^2=0  $$
and that contained in the unit circle is $z_0 = \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4r^2}}{2r}$ with the condition $a > 2r$. How can I calculate the residue at this point?